# Combine two operations in one command - awk

Tags: awk, gawk, mawk

I need to change

-
FROM

```
Car
Bus
```

-
TO

```
Helicopter
Airplane
```

This two commands are sufficient.

```
awk -i inplace '{sub(/Car/,"Helicopter")}1' file
awk -i inplace '{sub(/Bus/,"Airplane")}1' file
```

And this command is sufficient too.

```
sed -e 's/Car/Helicopter/' \
    -e 's/Bus/Airplane/' \
    -i file
```

### In "awk" is it possible to combine two operations in one command like "sed".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `awk -i inplace '{sub(/Car/,"Helicopter")} {sub(/Bus/,"Airplane")}1' file` did not work?

Comment: @AlexStragies This is the expected answer, I believe

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

`awk -i inplace '{sub(/Car/,"Helicopter")} {sub(/Bus/,"Airplane")}1' file`

Now you have 3 `Condition {Action}` blocks. `1` is a special case of a `condition {action}` block.

Or try this:

`awk -i inplace '{sub(/Car/,"Helicopter") ; sub(/Bus/,"Airplane")}1' file`

, because an action block can have more than one statement.

Comment: This works as long as the later substitutions do not substitute something already processed by an earlier substitution. Take as an example changing `goods` into `cargo` and then `car` into `automobile`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -i inplace '
    /^Car$/ { print "Helicopter"; next }
    /^Bus$/ { print "Airplane";   next }
            { print }' file
```

By matching against the complete line (using the `^` and `$` anchors), we make sure that we don't match the strings as substrings in other lines (e.g. the `Car` in `Cart`).  By acting on the found line and then immediately executing `next` we protect from changing a line into something that might trigger a later pattern.